# Android Layout: Is reusable component UI possible?

Tags: android, layout, code-reuse

I'll preface this with, I've just started learning Android so be gentle.
I come from an ASP.NET / Silverlight background so I was looking for something along the lines of controls.

I want to reuse a layout (a ListView item template) in other layouts.

Such that in my other layouts I can just add `<myListItem />` to show it.

Is this, or anything like it possible? or are there better ways?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is very possible; you just need to use the `<include />` tag.  Basically, you put your layout in a file, then you do:

```
<include layout="@layout/my_list_item_template" />
```

Romain Guy goes into detail on how to use it here: [http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/25/android-layout-trick-2-include-to-reuse/](https://web.archive.org/web/20100105185041/http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/25/android-layout-trick-2-include-to-reuse/)

([Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts))

(I am assuming that what you want is a reusable layout, not a custom component.  The difference being, a reusable layout is like reusing snippets of standard components, whereas a custom component is used when you need to extend the functionality of a particular widget, like a TextView or Button.  If you want a custom component, then you'll have to do a lot more legwork to Erich Douglass' answer for more on that.)

Comment: What if I want to customize the font of the reusable component?

Comment: pass font family in include tag <include layout="@layout/my_list_item_template"  android:fontFamily="@font/san-serif"/>